# Need help with proof: If R ⊆ S then R^(-1) ⊆ S^(-1)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

Here is what I have so far:

If R ⊆ S then R^(-1) ⊆ S^(-1).
Suppose R ⊆ S and that (a, b) ∈ R^(-1).  This means that (b, a) ∈ R.  Since S is a relation from A to B, that means that (b, a) ∈ S.  That would mean that (a, b) ∈ S^(-1), thus proving this statement true.

Comment: Why "So far"? What is missing? Why do you think something is missing?

Comment: What you have is fine: it’s a complete proof.

Comment: I had a school tutor look at it and he said that my reason for (b, a) ∈ S (Since S is a relation from A to B) is wrong.

Comment: It should make you suspicious if your argument doesn't use the hypothesis (and if some step does use the hypothesis, you should make this explicit.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument is fine, but for one thing (which is perhaps what your tutor was trying to get you to see).

The reason why $(b, a) \in S$, given the assumption $(b, a) \in R$, is that $S$ extends $R$, i.e. $R$ is contained in $S$. That's crucial -- it is evidently *not* enough just that $S$ is some relation or other from $A$ to $B$! So your "Since" clause is not right as it stands.

Comment: I can't believe I missed the obvious.  Thanks!